# Stellungnahme mit "Meiner Meinung nach"

Tags: sentence-structure, proficiency-test

I 'm about to complete B1 (Yay!) and Goethe Institut has changed the examination pattern from this year on. We're supposed to write a Stellungnahme in Teil *schreiben* and I wish to write my answer in a form that gives a good impression to the examiner, using words that a B1 candidate should be able to use.

For example, take this title "Ist unsere Gesellschaft kinderfeindlich?". Ideally I would start like this "Ich glaube das ist richtig" or "Ich halte das für richtig". I would however like to begin the phrase "Meiner Meinung nach diese Thema", but I am not sure about the construction.

> *Meiner Meinung nach diese Thema ist das Gesellschaft ist kinderfeindlich*

(or)

> *Meine Meinung ist das Gesellschaft ist kinderfeindlich.*

Am I right in both the cases? If yes, which one gives a good impression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to put the verb at the second possition. There are also a pair of grammar mistakes (*Thema* is neutral and *Gesellschaft*, feminine):

> Meiner Meinung nach ist die Gesellschaft kinderfeindlich.

or

> Meine Meinung über dieses Thema ist, dass die Gesellschaft kinderfeindlich ist.

To my taste, some context is missing: say, which society? in which country? You could try with this variant:

> Meiner Meinung nach ist die `Adjektiv zu bestimmtem Land` Gesellschaft kinderfeindlich.

or

> Ich bin der Meinung (or *Ich bin der Ansicht*), dass die `Adjektiv zu bestimmtem Land` Gesellschaft kinderfeindlich ist.

Comment: Oh, so "Meiner Meinung nach" is one phrase? what should come after nach?

Comment: @thandasoru Well, is not a *phrase* it's a "feste Nomen-Präposition Verbindung", i.e. you associate to the Substantive *Meinung* the preposition *nach*. After *nach* it comes the verb, when you put "Meiner Meinung nach" as first element in your sentence. The whole group of words is the first element, and the verb should be right after that.

Comment: Okay, just to make sure I understood properly, I'll take another example.
Q: Wie wichtig ist heute ein Hobby?
A: Meiner Meinung nach ist heute ein Hobby nicht so wichtig.

Am I correct?

Comment: @thandasoru Yes, correct! I would use, however, not *heute* (which means precisely this day) but *heutzutage* or *jetzt*.

Comment: Ich glaube, man hat Meinungen *zu* Themen, nicht *über* Themen.

Answer (score 9):

I want to add something that the other answer didn't focus on.
What can be confusing for a student of German is the dangling *nach*.
Usually *nach* is either a preposition followed by a noun-phrase

> Ich komme um Viertel nach vier.
>
> Ich gehe nach Hause.
>
> Es riecht nach Fisch.

or an adverb that is part of the verb

> Ich gucke etwas im Wörterbuch nach. – nachgucken

In the phrase in question however, *nach* is neither of the 2.

> Meiner Meinung nach …

*nach* is a postposition here and the case it demands is the Genitive. Postpositions are rare in German but there are more …

> Des Geldes wegen gehe ich arbeiten.

So instead of starting a block of speech as a preposition does this *nach* closes a block and thus the verb has to come after.

Comment: Wow, that's a great observation. It is true! I could not wrap my head around the usage because of this. You can see that my original sentence in the question is framed like the way you have explained. (nach diese Thema)