# Does the dative requirement go away in the construct "meiner Meinung nach?"

Tags: grammar

I was reading the following answer on Meta:
https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/615/2906

And noticed the following sentence:

> Diese Frage ist meiner Meinung nach ein Duplikat von dieser.

This seemed weird to me because I thought **nach** required the following article to be in the dative case, however the user did not use the dative case.  Was this a mistake on his/her part or does the dative requirement go away with the "meiner Meinung nach" construct?

Comment: The dative of „meine Meinung“ **is** „meiner Meinung“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I see that, however, are you implying that technically the expression could be "nach meiner Meinung?"  If so, why has the expression become "meiner Meinung nach?"

Comment: Both are possible: [*nach meiner Meinung/meiner Meinung nach ist die Sache längst entschieden*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Meinung)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz My question is less with the "meiner" part and more to do with the "nach ein" part.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/7595/5513

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic structure of this sentence is

> Diese Frage ist ein Duplikat von jener.

Then an *IMO* is inserted, which can be formulated as „meiner Meinung nach“ or „nach meiner Meinung“- In either case the *nach* refers to *meine Meinung*, and the insertion of the phrase does not alter the case of any part of the original sentence.

Comment: And for completion.. we're looking at Genitive of Meinung here, if the nach comes after and at Dative if it comes before it.

Comment: So you are saying it would be "meines Empfindens nach"?

Comment: Good point... I was actually thinking "wessen Meinung nach" but that totally doesn't refer to "nach" :). I think it is not clear for "nach" though ... "meines Wissens nach", "meinem Empfinden nach"... both is right, depending on the exact words.

Comment: I agree, it is unclear.

Comment: @Emanuel Setz doch mal Namen ein und teste, ob du ein s anhängst oder nicht ;) "Emanuel Empfinden nach" ... Nope.

Comment: @Em1... ja, das war auch mein gedanklicher Fehler... es ist immer "Emanuels Emofinden" denn das ist die Entität. Die kann man dann in alle Fälle setzen. "Emanuels Empf. ist komisch." "Ich kenne Emanuels Empf." "Ich habe von Emanuels Empf gehört" "Statt Emanuels Empfindens interessiert mich sein Haarschnitt."

Comment: I'm a bit unsure now. Is it *genitive* or *dative*? Maybe a hint to the correct case can be added to the answer.

Comment: Okay, probably *genitive* ? But that would mean `meines Empfindens nach`, wouldn't it?